# Não está passando valor variável JS para PHP via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**JavaScript**

```
$('#save-update').data('eventId', info.event.id);

$('#delete-update').click(function (info) {
        info.preventDefault();        
        let eventID = $('#save-update').data('eventId');        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/delete-events.php',             
            data: eventID,       
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                location.reload();                       
            }
        })
    });
```

**PHP**

`$id = $_POST['eventID'];`

Não está chegando o valor do id para o arquivo PHP.
Notice: Undefined index: eventID

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você precisa enviar a variavel em um objeto JS

```js
$('#delete-update').click(function (info) {
        info.preventDefault();        
        let eventID = $('#save-update').data('eventId');        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/delete-events.php',             
            data: {eventID:eventID},       // Alterado aqui
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                location.reload();                       
            }
        })
    });
```

***Explicando***

```
           ⬐ ex. $_POST['eventID']
data: { eventID : eventID },
              Valor ⬏
```

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito, o PHP n ta conseguindo pegar o valor. Ele esta fazendo a requisição e até dei um alert em eventID no JS e ta saindo o valor do id, porém n vai para o PHP.

Comment: remove a linha do "processData" e do "contentType"

Comment: Isso, deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: feliz em te ajudar 